# HTTP Response for HP ALM Request is 302 instead of 200

Tags: rest, perl

I am using a Perl script with the
[`REST::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client) module
to send requests to the *HP Application Lifecycle Management* (ALM).

The URL request works fine from a browser (giving `200 OK` XML response), but requests from the program to retrieve defects from a project return `302 Found` instead of `200 OK`.

```
$client->GET($api_proto.'://'.$api_url.':'.$api_port.'/qcbin/rest/domains/my-domain/projects/my-project/defects/?login-form-required=y');
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using HTTP then you should become familiar with [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) which has this

> **302 Found**

> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.
> Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD
> continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.  This response
> is only cacheable if indicated by a Cache-Control or Expires header
> field.

Now, referring to the documentation for
[`REST::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client), it says

```
# Requests can optionally automatically follow redirects and auth, defaults to
# false 
$client->setFollow(1);
```

You will have to learn to read documentation if you intend to get anywhere on your own